# How do you configure RadRails to use Rails installed through RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, aptana, radrails

How do I properly setup Aptana RadRails if I've installed Rails through RVM?

I followed the install on http://railstutorial.org/ but my script paths don't work: e.g.:

- 'rails' path: */home/marius/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails3gemset/bin/rails*
- Detected path: *Not Detected*

Comment: Got any luck..? I am also having the same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing ruby through rvm, I was able to get eclipse to use that install by:

```
In Eclipse, go to Window -> Preferences.
In the Ruby/Interpreters tab click "Search"
```

For me this found all of the ruby installs from rvm, and it added them to the interpreters list. I edited the "Name" field to include the version number for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

try to run this in the command line. It will show you real path to the available rail script for current environment.

$ which rails

Answer (score 1):

In Aptana Studio 3 (build: 3.0.8.201201201658) there is no Window -> preferences. If you have a .rvmrc in your project work directory, stating for instance:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p0@mygemset
```

... then Aptana should pick up the correct environment; in this case using ruby-1.9.3-p0 with gemset mygemset. Don't forget to run build install or build update (when you updated your Gemfile) from your project working directory path.

I must add that Aptana Studio 3 seems a bit buggy when it comes to picking up the correct environment, especially when trying to use ruby-debug-ide19.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with just `/home/marius/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/rails` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run eclipse/aptana from a terminal session.

Answer (score 0):

### Without RVM  :

Please type command `whereis ruby` in console.
you will get the path like `/usr/bin/ruby` or `/usr/local/bin/ruby` to check which is correct  interpreter path `/usr/bin/ruby -v` if you get version. that is your interpreter.

### With RVM  :

Please type command: `rvm info`

```
binaries:
    ruby: "/home/<USERNAME>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby"
```

copy this path and paste wherever you need enter you interpreter path.

It worked for me. and I hope it will help others as well.

Cheers!